# Using Raster Calculator in ArcPy gives ERROR 000989

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000989

I am creating a watermask from the DEM in ArcGIS DEsktop 10.5 python script. After executing the tasks, at the end I am getting the MIN elevation from Statistics_analysis.

Now I am doing RasterCalculator_sa() on the constant raster I have calculated above and executing the following

```
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("\"%constant_raster_ %\" * float(%value%)", rastercalc)
where (value=MIN_elevation)
```

but my script is breaking at this line and displaying the error which I have attached.

[image]

I have exported this script through my model builder and have attached the raster calculator window snapshot.

[image]

Can anyone help?

---

I have also tried running the following

```
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa(constant_raster_ * float(value), rastercalc)
```

Its giving me error:

> Type error: cannot multiply sequence by non-int of type float

Comment: What are the "\" for? Constant raster should have no space before the % also I don't see why you're using quotes around the constant raster, it's a model variable right?. I would use arcpy.sa. functions but that's more of a personal preference. You can produce a working raster calc in model builder then export it to python script to see what the syntax looks like if you're really stumped.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Following is the exact line which i see after producing script from the model builder

arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("%constant raster %\" * float(%Value%)", rastercalc)

But as in my script the constant raster path is store in constant_raster_ thats why I replace it with

Comment: I'd have to see more of the script itself to comment but the use of the model builder variable %'s is not valid in a python script, I would urge you to use raster objects with arcpy.sa functions, I find it more intuitive, you would write like rastercalc = constant_raster_ * arcpy.sa.Float(value) where constant_raster_ is the result of a previous operation or raster object created by arcpy.Raster(r'c:\full\path\to\raster.ext') - much simpler to read.

Comment: So its mean by using arcpy.sa there is no need of using RasterCalculator_sa() function? the end result (as compare to the model builder) will be the same?

Comment: Yes. Have a read of Con https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000 which I believe represents the idiom shift quite nicely, you no longer need to have physical rasters as intermediate steps but you can save them (see Raster Object https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000 for the save() method) any rasters created during the execution of a script simply disappear at the end and you can use mathematical operators. I'm sure once you try it you'll like the new methods.

Comment: One thing which i have forgot to mentioned above is, the constant_raster_ is a raster dataset.
i have run the following line and its giving me the following  error

rastercalc=constant_raster_ * arcpy.sa.Float(value)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TKX4YltaMwW6sI8LQH8l5Do0mqZ_ETsf

Comment: You can't use the raster calculator in a Python script.  See here:https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then whats the way around of RasterCalculator in python? As i have successful converted all my model builder to the python script and this is the last step. You quick response would be highly appreciated.